# Coven Witches Constantly Teleporting

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I am playing Minecraft 1.7.10, in a custom modpack. I have the Witchery Mod version `1.7.10-0.24.1`. While roaming around my base, my coven witches will (without prompt from me) teleport to me and walk around. I have used a seer stone in the past to summon them for a ritual. Did I do something wrong? How do I fix this? Is there a config file I can edit to disable this?

Comment: What plugins are you using?

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. Also, what mods?

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. Updated

Comment: @Beminfire Updated

Comment: Hellooooo? @rivermont-WillB.

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, you aren't doing anything wrong! Witches which are a part of your coven will randomly teleport to you at times and wander around - it's normal and can't be prevented. Well, you could kill all your coven witches, but that's a bit extreme and probably counter-productive ;)

References:
Wiki- https://sites.google.com/site/witcherymod/coven-witch
alongside personal experience.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so with some digging,

```
/Users/(your name)/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/config/witchery.cfg
```

Or your minecraft configuration file directory contains a line reading

```
B:AllowCovenWitchVisits=true
```

Just change that to `false`, restart your server and or minecraft client, and you'll be good!